# Subversion/Ankhsvn: How to change status from "copied and modified" to added

Tags: visual-studio, svn, diff, commit

When implementing new stuff in my Visual Studio (2015) solutions, **I often copy existing files and heavily modify their content, instead of starting completely from scratch.**

Now, when committing these files to the Subversion repo, the "Pending Changes" windows (we use AnkhSVN) these files have their Change information correctly set to "Copied and Modified". A diff is possible to the original content. However, in many cases, I would rather have these files to show as "new" or "added", because this better suits their heavily modified state. Heck, the most of the time the do implement a complete new feature.

**How to change the "Change" state from "Copied and Modified" to "New" in the AnkhSVN "Pending Changes" window?**

Note: In the TortoiseSVN Commit window, these files show as added, but are annotated as "copied from" in the hover window. Also, they allow to compare to base, which I do not want in this case.

Note2: The opposite case is also happening. When newly generating files (for EF Entities for example) these show as "New over Deleted" (when previously deleted) but I would have the rather display simply as "changed".